# How can I increase the number of frames displayed in Webstorm debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm using Webstorm to debug a node application. I've noticed that no more than 10 frames are ever displayed in the 'Frames' pane in the Debug area.

How can I show the entire list of frames?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this limitation comes from NodeJS debugging engine. The same number of frames is shown when application is debugged using node-inspector.